# Solving for the efficient subsidy amount with an externality

Tags: microeconomics, pareto-efficiency, externalities, subsidies, lagrangian

I am dealing with a problem that is set up as follows: Actors A and B get utility from consumption ($c_i$) and disutility from safety measures ($s_i$), however their chance of getting sick is reduced by how much safety measures they buy: $-4(1-s_a)(1-s_b)$. T
Their respective utility functions are the same, so for A it is:
$$
U_a = c_a - (s_a)^2 - 4(1-s_a)(1-s_b)
$$
Both A and B are endowed with two units of labor. There are two firms, C and S, which produce consumption goods and safety measures. C's production function is $C=L_c$ and S's is $S=L_s$. A and B sell their all their labor to C, S, or both at price $p_l$ and must buy $c$ and $s$ at prices $p_c$ and $p_s$.

I have already determined that the Pareto efficient quantity for both $s_a$ and $s_b$ is $7/10$. The prices, with one normalized to 1, all equal each other and thus all equal 1. Now I am being asked to find the subsidy that will lead to that quantity. This is done by inserting the subsidy $t$ into the consumer's problem, accounting for the total cost of the subsidy $t(s_a+s_b)$, which will be split equally between A and B.
For A:
$$maxU_a = c_a - (s_a)^2 - 4(1-s_a)(1-s_b) s. t. ((p_s - t)s_a + p_cc_a =< 2p_l - \frac t2 (s_a+s_b))
$$
Working through the Langrangian with the following first order conditions:
$$
\frac {dL}{dc_a} = 1 - λp_c = 0
$$
$$
\frac {dL}{ds_a} = -2s_a + 4(1-s_b) - λ\frac t2 - λ(p_s-t) = 0
$$
$$
\frac {dL}{dλ} = 2p_l - \frac {t}{2}(s_a+s_b) - p_cc_a - (p_s - t)s_a = 0
$$
Since I already know the efficient quantities, and the prices in equilibrium, I should be able to use them to solve for $t$. Once I work through it, I get $t= \frac {12}{5}$. However, according to my instructor I should get $t= \frac {6}{5}$. I am almost certain I did not make any algebra mistakes while solving, which suggests to me that there is a problem with my setup or process. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?